# Php MySql birthday query between dates ignoring year

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I am trying to get upcoming birthdays from a database so I can create a mailing list for those customers.
**$pet_bdate** - The admin supplies a date with JQuery datepicker in the format dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'.
**$plus_days** - He can also choose For Dates Range - Plus Days from Chosen Date from 0 to 14.

Server config:
Php v 5.2.17
MySQL v 5.5.23
(So several more advanced Php functions don't work as well as MySql)

The column ***petbday*** is of type **DATE**.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` c LEFT JOIN `pet` p ON (c.customer_id = p.customer_id) 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(p.petbday, '%m-%d') 
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(2014-04-13, '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(2014-04-13, INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%m-%d')) 
GROUP BY c.customer_id ORDER BY firstname, lastname, email
```

And here is the Php code that makes it:

```
SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "pet` p ON (c.customer_id = p.customer_id) 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(p.petbday, '%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(" . $pet_bdate . ", '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(" . $pet_bdate . ", INTERVAL " . $plus_days . " DAY), '%m-%d')) GROUP BY c.customer_id ORDER BY firstname, lastname, email
```

This query returns **ZERO rows** for a date that has birthdays in the DB.

How can I hand a formatted date to query so to ignore year?

I tried formating it prior to handing it to query but when it comes to calculating dates with Php I got a little mixed up.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using DAYOFYEAR instead of string comparison.

Update: I also need to add that your dates should be wrapped in colons to work properly '2004-04-15'.

Comment: Thanx. I have mentioned it in my solution prior to seeing your update :-)

Comment: This does not work if you have begin/ end across the year border

Comment: using DAYOFYEAR will also return false positives for people born in leap years after the end of february

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` c LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "pet` p 
ON (c.customer_id = p.customer_id) 
WHERE (DAYOFYEAR(p.petbday) BETWEEN (DAYOFYEAR('" . $pet_bdate . "')) 
AND (DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD('" . $pet_bdate . "', INTERVAL " . $plus_days . " DAY))))
GROUP BY c.customer_id ORDER BY firstname, lastname, email
```

So in order to get **DATE RANGE** I used ***DAYOFYEAR*** (as [andig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608395/andig) suggested) on the column itself **p.petbday** and on both range dates:

```
$pet_bdate - ORIGINAL STARTING DATE
DATE_ADD('" . $pet_bdate . "', INTERVAL " . $plus_days . " DAY) - ORIGINAL 
STARTING DATE PLUS INTERVAL DAYS
```

I used **DATE_ADD** because my ***MySQL*** version is **v5.5.23**

NOTE: Both dates need to be passed as string (hence the single quotes).

Hope you found this useful...

Comment: I still don't think this will fully work. 1) DATE_ADD is a MYSQL function and has nothing to do with PHP. 2) DAYOFYEAR will wrap at 365 so you'll need to take care of that as well.

Comment: Well it does...as for #1 - you were right and it was fixed. as for #2 - I have chosen a fixed year that is a leap year - 2000, so when choosing a birth date or range you have the option of choosing any date existing on a calendar. AFAIK MySQL DAYOFYEAR() returns day of the year for a date. The return value is within the range of 1 to 366 so for someone who is choosing a dob for a mailing list this is very convenient...I will post the jquery datepicker script for others...thank you for your help and guidance.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $('input[name="pet_bdate"]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: '2000:2000', // one year - leap year
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: false, // NO **Year** drop down box
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: new Date('2000/01/01'), // START date
        maxDate: new Date('2000/12/31'), // END date
    beforeShow: function(input, instance) {
      var firstDate = new Date('2000/01/01');
            if (this.val != 0) {
              $('input[name="pet_bdate"]').datepicker( 'setDate' , $('input[name="pet_bdate"]').val());
            } else {
              $('input[name="pet_bdate"]"]').datepicker('setDate', firstDate);
            }
    }
    });
  $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible');
```